# Null Pointer when setting onClickListener on a button in Android app

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm trying to set an onClickListener for a button which on a click starts a new activity. I am getting a Null Pointer Exception when I try to set the listener to the button and I'm clueless as to why. It is a very simple program and I have done this before. Here is my code:

**Main Activity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button next;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.next:
        // Signin button clicked
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class));
        break;
    }
}
}
```

and **xml layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".SplashScreen" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next Activity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.SplashScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at com.example.test.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:21)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-28 14:16:19.387: E/AndroidRuntime(11507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
```

The error is on Line 21 and Line 21 is this:

`next.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: What is line 21 in `SplashScreen.java`?. The buttons belongs to splashscreen.xml??

Comment: @Raghunandan he said in last line that " The error is on Line 21 and Line 21 is this: "

Comment: The null is coming from SplashScreen.java, not MainActivity.java, can you post the code for your SplashScreen.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan no that does not seem like line 21 `SplashScreen.java`. Does it?. Posted code is `MainActivity.java`

Comment: @Raghunandan yes you right, user must post splash screen code, sorry for fast judgment

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: error is on SplashScreen.java 21 line, not MainActivity.java 21 line**

Are you sure that layout you have given is `activity_main.xml`? Because it looks like it's not `activity_main.xml`, because `findViewById` doesn't find `next` Button.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have posted seems to be correct, though the error stack says that the exception is being thrown in **com.example.test/com.example.test.SplashScreen** and **NOT MainActivity**. Debug into that class, or post its code here.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.SplashScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score -5):

"this" is your activity, not a Listener.  Try this:

```
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // What do do when "next" is clicked
       }
});
```

Comment: did u noticed this line? `extends Activity implements OnClickListener`

Comment: wrong. It's perfectly correct if your class implements that interface.